# Display Leaves Status for 31 days

Tags: mysql, case

I have these two tables.

```
Leave Table

from_date       to_date          user_id
2011-12-01    2011-12-01         1
2011-12-01    2011-12-07         2
2011-11-02    2011-11-04         3


user table
id      name
1       john
2       Caren
3       Sam
```

Now I need to display output in this way

```
NAME     1   2   3   4   5   6   7  ......up to 31 days
john     L       
Caren    L   L   L   L   L   L   L       
Sam          L   L   L
```

So how can we write a query for this?

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for you;-)

```
SELECT
  u.*,
  IF(1 BETWEEN DAYOFMONTH(from_date) AND DAYOFMONTH(to_date), 'L', NULL) '1',
  IF(2 BETWEEN DAYOFMONTH(from_date) AND DAYOFMONTH(to_date), 'L', NULL) '2',
  IF(3 BETWEEN DAYOFMONTH(from_date) AND DAYOFMONTH(to_date), 'L', NULL) '3',

  IF(31 BETWEEN DAYOFMONTH(from_date) AND DAYOFMONTH(to_date), 'L', NULL) '31'
FROM test.user u
  JOIN `leave` l
    ON u.id = l.user_id
```

Add other fields to the query, and add WHERE filter to select exact month.

Comment: I think it can be simplified, additional table and pivot table should be used.